# Adding an adjustable delay circuit

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, bjt, delay

The solutions presented in [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/639798/best-way-to-design-a-circuit-for-the-following-and-logic) provide 12 V output when battery voltage is above a certain threshold and an inline switch is pressed.

Here is the schematic for the chosen answer:
[image]

What would be the most appropriate way of adding an adjustable delay (0-5 s) such that the output goes to 12 V only once the conditions are met and the delay is satisfied? Adding an RC on the output would work but it could potentially load the next stage and it adds a delay on turn off as well.

Here is one solution using a 555 timer:

[image]

[image]

Is there a simpler way of achieving this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

[image]

The VOUT is the voltage you want to delay (just connect it to your circuit)
the VOUT + DELAY is the voltage after the delay.

Whenever VOUT is low, the capacitor is connected to the ground via the MOSFET, and when the VOUT turns high, the MOSFET stops conducting and the capacitor starts charging.

When the VOUT turns from high to low, the MOSFET discharges the capacitor immediately, and the VOUT+DELAY voltage goes low.